# Invalid team ID in signature

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

We are working on an app, that was originally created by other developers. They added our account to iTunes Connect as Admin role and to Member Center as Admin too. We added that account to Xcode and we've chosen "Team" setting under Target to match the right team.

When we are trying to archive and upload new version, Xcode returns error:

> No accounts with iTunes Connect access.

But if I try to log in to iTunes Connect, it works normally.

I tried uploading new version by exporting .ipa and uploading in via Application Loader. After unsuccessful upload, I get a mail like the following:

> Invalid team ID in signature - The code signature in bundle 'com.example' at 'example.app' has a team identifier value that is different from your team identifier 'EXAMPLE'.

Under keychain certificates, there is iPhone Distribution Certificate with that team name. How to resolve this whole problem?

Comment: You maded your build with wrong team.
Try to use correct team in <YOUR-Project> -> General

Comment: Under General, we have chosen our account and under that we picked the right team. No errors during build, errors after we try to upload to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Same problem here. The app enters review but then a minute later becomes invalid binary here with Invalid team ID in signature. I wrote to developer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the target of your Xcode project in the main settings page (when you first click on the target) you will see a drop down called Team.  You need to make sure you have the right team selected that goes with the proper bundle I'd

Comment: Just commented under post above. We have picked the right team under that option.

Comment: Hmmm Do you have the key AND the distribution cert?

Comment: I think yes. I removed every cert and account from keychain and xcode and re added again. When something was missing xcode warned me and I reseted everything. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you build a distribution ipa from your machine?

Comment: I can build iOS App Store Deployment, but as stated above I get "Invalid team id in signature". 
It is visible from Signing Identity that it uses distribution profile with wrong Team ID. This is visible in the step, before I click export.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is still relevant.

So what you would normally need to do is:

1. Go to the developer portal, and in the Certificates, IDs and Profiles choose Certificates > Production. You should be able to download the Distribution certificate.
2. Go to the Provisioning Profiles > Distribution (same page, menu on the left) and choose and download and double click the provisioning profile for your app.

Now you should be able to choose this Distribution Certificate/Provisioning profile combo in xcode to build and sign your app.

We develop white labelled apps, so our account actually manages over 40 other apple dev accounts (since apple guidelines say that apps need to be submitted by content provider even when developed by 3rd party).

About the error you received: when we transfer app from our main apple dev account to respective apple account of the client, we do get the warning you mentioned as well. Yet even after receiving the warning, our apps get uploaded/approved. This happens because in past the app has been developed under a different team (and apple prefixes the team-id from dev portal to the bundle-id to finally identify apps on dev portal/appstore connect, it seems).

So what happens to you I think is that you dont have the distribution certificate/provisioning profile sorted out properly. Do you use just xcode, or a different tool to build/sign your app(s) - like Visual Studio for Mac? You would need to sort the provisioning combo there as well.

If you look to your keychain, in the "My Certificates" section you should see the team that invited you as admin to manage their apple account, and this entry should have a little arrow next to it, if you click it, you should also see that there is a private key associated to this certificate.

You might need to manually download all of the provisioning files in the xcode tho, in my experience double clicking the provisioning profile file downloaded from portal sometimes doesnt do the trick. If its the same for you, go to the xcode > Preferences > Account > click on your account in xcode, and on the right you should see all the teams that you are part of. Click on the team and click on "Download manual profiles".

If you use Visual Studio for Mac, you also need to add your account in the Visual Studio for Mac > Preferences > Publishing > Apple Developer Accounts. If this is empty, just add your Apple dev account, login, and you will also see a list of teams you are part of. If it syncs well, you can actually just leave the certificate/provisioning combo on Automatic in Visual Studio, and it will manage it for you.